# Private browsing in firefox- Crashing

Tags: firefox

I was browsing in firefox under Private mode, then i tried to open another firefox window and tried to do private browsing in that too by ctrl+shift+p and firefox crashed.

Cant i use private browsing in two different firefox windows.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are in private browsing mode, all additional windows you open are already in private browsing mode. If you press ctrl+shift+p again you are basically closing private browsing mode.